# How to displaying &amp; in Labels and ListView

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey, delphi-xe

Writing a multi-platform phone directory app using FireMonkey in Delphi 10 Seattle

The data is stored in XML file.
The screen has a ListView showing peoples names and a detail tab showing the name, address, phone #s etc.

When the name: **Doe, John & Jane** 
is displayed it is treated differently in the two components.

```
The ListView shows:  Doe, John & Jane
The NameLabel shows: Doe, John Jane
```

If I escape the **&** in the XML: **Doe, John && Jane**

```
The ListView shows:  Doe, John && Jane
The NameLabel shows: Doe, John & Jane
```

Is there a property I can set or code I can attach to an event on either component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` is used, by default, to identify the keyboard accelerator key of a label control. To change this default behaviour, set the [`PrefixStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TPresentedTextControl.PrefixStyle) property to `TPrefixStyle.NoPrefix`.

> Determines whether the ampersand character (&) is considered as a
>   special prefix character.
>
> The default value is TPrefixStyle.HidePrefix, which means that the
>   (first) ampersand is hidden at run-time.

This is a public rather than published property, and so you will need to set this in code.